# OSM tile server, combination of my own private data and OpenStreetMap priodic updates

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have set up an OSM tile server and also an OverpassAPI on my own server. While I was doing that, I understood that OpenStreetMap provide minutely, hourly and daily updates. So my servers can be sync with it.

On the other hand, I want to add my own private data into my server without pushing them to OpenStreetMap servers.

My question is that can I have a tile server(or OverpassAPI server) that feed from both sources(my own private data and periodic updates of OpenStreetMap)?

Any assistance would be grealty appreciated.

NOTE: Technically speaking, I am really confused. I have couple of questions but the most one is that I don't have any idea about ids. I know that OpenStreetMap data(nodes, ways and relations) have positive ids and therefore my own data could get negative. But is it a real solution?

UPDATE: *I have also asked this question in the support site for OpenStreetMap  ([here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/70897/osm-tile-server-combination-of-my-own-private-data-and-openstreetmap-priodic-updates)). There are also some similar question(i.e. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172316/osm-update-without-losing-own-additional-data),[this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295767/keeping-my-changes-up-to-date-with-osm)). None of them have accepted answer.*

Comment: cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/70897/osm-tile-server-combination-of-my-own-private-data-and-openstreetmap-priodic-updates

Comment: That's mine, too. Is it illegal? I mentioned there that is a copy of this post. Should I mention something here?

Comment: Yes, you always should. Otherwise people here will try answering your question although it might already be answered somewhere else. This will waste other people's time.

Comment: Of course. The question is edited now!